# Read numbers from .txt in parent process and send it to child process with pipe and write it

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent

I am trying to send double numbers from parent to child, but it prints only the first and then stops.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <sys/unistd.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pip[2];
    int fd, n;
    double x1;
    double x2;

    pipe(pip);

    pid = fork();

    fd = open("numbers.txt", O_RDONLY);

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        close(pip[1]);

        read(pip[0], &x2, sizeof(double));

        printf("%lf\n", x2);

        close(pip[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pip[0]);
        n = read(fd, &x1, sizeof(double));

        while(n)
        {
            write(pip[1], &x1, sizeof(double));
        }

        close(pip[1]);

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am closing the pipe when I try to read or write and another problem is, that it prints 0.000000 not the actual value of the number.

Comment: You're missing a lot of `#include` and it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: there are all the includes in myinclude.h:

Comment: I added all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it prints only the first and then stops.

note the child (try to) read only **one** float before to leave, so even you sent several only the first is print

Doing

> ```
> n = read(fd, &x1, sizeof(double));
> ```

supposes *numbers.txt* contains the binary representation of doubles, but because of the extension *txt* I think they contains numbers in their ASCII form and not binary. Note also to loop while *n* is not null is not compatible with the fact *read* return -1 on EOF (not 0)

if I modify your program to read them from their ascii form and I add a loop in the child all is ok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pip[2];
    FILE * fd;
    double x1;
    double x2;

    pipe(pip);

    pid = fork();

    fd = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        close(pip[1]);

        while (read(pip[0], &x2, sizeof(double)) == sizeof(double))
          printf("%f\n", x2);

        close(pip[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pip[0]);

        while (fscanf(fd, "%lf", &x1) == 1)
        {
          write(pip[1], &x1, sizeof(double));
        }

        close(pip[1]);

        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall p.c
/tmp % cat numbers.txt 
1.2
3.14
/tmp % ./a.out
1.200000
3.140000
/tmp %
```